# print out the record it says only true

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using R to write down the code of where each coefficient has significant impact on the model. It works fine, but since I have 500 records, it is hard to look at the console and locate the record I want.

My question is, is there a way to print the record number where it says TRUE?

```
model1 <- lm(price~area+bedrooms+bathrooms+stories, data = house)
DFBETAS <- dfbetas(model1)  # absolute of dfbetas is compared with 2/sqrt(n)
DFBETAS > 2/sqrt(n) | DFBETAS <  -2/sqrt(n)
```

[image]

Comment: It's very simple. Delete ALL your environment. Write a code to reproduce that final data you shared here. Now take that code and paste it here. Think about it. How in the world can we test the solutions we might want to offer, if we don't have the code you have used?

Answer (score 2):

We don't have your data, so here's an example with a built-in dataset. I make a linear model, then make a data frame with TRUE for any values exceeding your threshold. Then I add a column noting the row, and finally output just the subset of rows where any columns (among columns 1:3) are TRUE.

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt + gear, data = mtcars)
df <- as.data.frame(abs(dfbetas(fit)) > 2/sqrt(nrow(mtcars)))
df$row = 1:nrow(mtcars)
df[rowSums(df[,1:3]) > 0,] # better, suggested by @r2evans
# df[which(apply(df[, 1:3], 1, any)), ]  # my original suggestion
```

Result

```
                  (Intercept)    wt  gear row
Chrysler Imperial        TRUE  TRUE FALSE  17
Fiat 128                FALSE  TRUE FALSE  18
Toyota Corolla           TRUE  TRUE FALSE  20
Toyota Corona            TRUE FALSE FALSE  21
Ford Pantera L           TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  29
Maserati Bora            TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  31
```

Comment: Similarly (and slightly faster with this data, and _much_ faster with many more rows): `df[rowSums(df[,1:3]) > 0,]`, no need for the `$row` column (and the `[,1:3]` here is just to work the same in case `$row` is there ... otherwise not needed).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `which()` function in R.

Comment: While I recognize that the question is incomplete and can easily be improved, and that `which` is very likely the cornerstone of most potential answers, I suggest that answers on SO really should be (in many/most situations) as complete and reproducible as we hope questions will be. At times it is inconvenient (which is likely why many choose to not attempt answers), but if the answer really is this simple and there are no obvious duplicates questions to point to, then I suggest using a canonical dataset and contriving a _simple_ demonstration would be very beneficial for the OP and others.